# What is the difference between collide and clash?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-meaning, difference, verbs

And what is more appropriate here: He was a great manager but he  __________ ( collided, clashed) with time-keeping. Why?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

> Definition of collide
> intransitive verb
> 1 : to come together with solid or direct impact
> The car collided with a tree.
> Two helicopters collided.
> 2 : CLASH
> colliding cultures
> Science and religion collided in the court.

Collide can mean clash, but also mean to come in impact to.

> Definition of clash (Entry 1 of 2)
> intransitive verb
> 1 : to make a clash
> cymbals clashed
> 2 : to come into conflict
> where ignorant armies clash by night
> — Matthew Arnold
> also : to be incompatible
> the colors clashed

In this case, you mean ‘to come into conflict with’ so either could be used.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clash

Comment: I find both verbs odd in this context, but _collide_ has more suggestion of a literal, physical collision to me.